# No database tables are found

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have a sqlite database and with the programm sqliteStudio I can connect and save things. My Problem is the connection to the database with node.js with the npm package "sqlite". Every time I want to do a query it can't find the table. My code:

```
  const connection = await sqlite.open('./db.sqlite');
  const data = await connection.run("select * from item")
```

After that with `console.log(connection)`, I get the following message with looks good in my opinion

```
  driver: Database { open: true, filename: './db.sqlite', mode: 65542 },
  Promise: [Function: Promise] }
```

But the output of `console.log(data)` is always a error message:

```
{ Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: item errno: 1, code: 'SQLITE_ERROR' }
```

I think it is a problem with async/await or with my .sqlite file but I don't know

Comment: Be sure your DB file can be found. When you try to open a DB file which dosn't exist, sqlite creates a new empty one by default. 
Maybe you open this new and empty DB, so your table can't be found.

Comment: This was exactly my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

you are right, you have to use the arrow-function to wait until database is open, see here:

```
 // database is not existing
    console.log('open database and create table');
    db = new sqlite3.Database('./event.db',() => {
      db.run('CREATE TABLE logTable(logfile TEXT,logdate TEXT,referto TEXT, area TEXT,status TEXT,action TEXT)',() => {
      ...
      });

// if db is existing
  db = new sqlite3.Database('./event.db'() => {
    ...
});
```

Comment: if you are using sqlite3, but i use sqlite package